# Remove uni-grams from a list of bi-grams

Tags: python, list, file-handling, n-gram

I have managed to create 2 lists from text documents. The first is my bi-gram list:

```
keywords = ['nike shoes','nike clothing', 'nike black', 'nike white']
```

and a list of stop words:

```
stops = ['clothing','black','white']
```

I want to remove the Stops from my Keywords list. Using the above example, the output I am after should look like this:

```
new_keywords = ['nike shoes','nike', 'nike', 'nike'] --> eventually I'd like to remove those dupes.
```

This is what I've done so far:

```
keywords = open("keywords.txt", "r")
new_keywords = keywords.read().split(",")
stops = open("stops.txt","r")
new_stops = stops.read().split(",")
[i for i in new_keywords if i not in new_stops]
```

The problem I am having is that it is looking for the 2 words combos rather than the single word stops....

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in steps. First define a helper function:

```
def removeStop(bigram, stops):
    return ' '.join(w for w in bigram.split() if not w in stops)
```

And then:

```
[removeStop(i,new_stops) for i in new_keywords]
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have the 2 lists this will do what you want:

```
new_keywords = []

for k in keywords:
    temp = False

    for s in stops:
        if s in k:
           new_keywords.append(k.replace(s,""))
           temp = True

    if temp == False:
        new_keywords.append(k)
```

This will create a list like you posted:

```
['nike shoes', 'nike ', 'nike ', 'nike ']
```

To eliminate the doubles do this:

```
new_keywords = list(set(new_keywords))
```

So the final list looks like this:

```
['nike shoes', 'nike ']
```

[image]

Comment: thanks so much for your feedback, I do have a list, however, your above suggestion didnt produce the result you suggested it would. What you've got does make sense to me, but not clear why it didnt work.

Comment: Strange. I just tested it again and works fine for me.What version of Python are you using? I added a screeshot that shows exactly what I did.

Comment: works. it was me, not you :) thanks a mil. all solved and very useful!