# Conditional Freq Dist uni-grams from n-grams

Tags: python, list, nltk, frequency-distribution

If I have such a list of tuples:

```
train = [('pad thai', 'FOOD#QUALITY'),
 ('Ginger House', 'RESTAURANT#GENERAL'),
 ('fried dumplings', 'FOOD#QUALITY'),
 ('Chinese restaurant', 'RESTAURANT#GENERAL'),
 ('customer service', 'SERVICE#GENERAL'),
 ('management', 'SERVICE#GENERAL')]
```

I can use `freq = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist((a, category) for a, category in train)` to get the frequencies of whole phrase in a category, but if I want to store just the frequencies of unigrams, how would I do this, preferably in a list comprehension? I have come across this solution: [Remove uni-grams from a list of bi-grams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490160/remove-uni-grams-from-a-list-of-bi-grams) which is helpful, but would like something more concise if possible.

Comment: Please make an attempt, then if you get stuck come back and ask questions.

Comment: The first answer in the question you link to is pretty concise-- three lines of code. If it really doesn't meet your needs, please edit your question to explain why.